# How to install older builds of Oracle VIrtualBox VM on Lubuntu 20.04 (details provided)

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, virtualbox, lubuntu

Need to install older build of Oracle VIrtualBox VM - 5.2.40 or 5.2.XX.
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_2
These are the older builds.

On Oracle VIrtualBox, they told me this:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=101463&p=492590#p492590
In a nutshell to install the newest version, but I can't use it.
ON the links above you can, too, see what I did in order to try to install Oracle VIrtualBox VM on Lubuntu 20.04.
In addition to that, I also tried just to install the specified build by using this instruction from the official page https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Autput/input

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package virtualbox-5.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'virtualbox-5.2' has no installation candidate
```

I ve tried to install it via qAPt Package Installer.
Nothing. I have the internet file download saved in my documents.

Best regards

Comment: That is not the right answer. I just copied the commands from the Oracle VB page here for you to see it. I did not use that command you mentioned. I ve used sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu repository for a particular release (like 20.04) has only a single version of each package. The repository does not have older versions.

- Virtualbox 5.2 (only) is in the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.
- Virtualbox 6.1 (only) is in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories.

You can download older packages from https://packages.ubuntu.com or from https://launchpad.net/virtualbox/+packages or from Virtualbox upstream directly. Or you can temporarily add the 18.04 repositories to your 20.04 apt sources. **WARNING**: Older packages and non-Ubuntu packages have not been tested with Ubuntu 20.04: Perhaps they will work, perhaps they won't.

An easy, supported solution is to install Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) instead of Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal). Then use Vbox 5.2 that's in the Bionic repositories. Ubuntu 18.04 is community-supported for three more years.